# Know if node is in view, edit, delete, etc. in page.tpl

Tags: 7, nodes

I need to verify, in `page.tpl` file, if page is currently showing a node for viewing, editing, or deleting purposes.

I found I can write `arg(2)=="edit"` to verify if it is in "edit mode", but how to do for delete (`arg(2)` is empty such as for view).

What is the correct way to get this information?

Thank you

Comment: The path for deleting the nodes is actually `/node/%node/delete`. What do you mean by `arg(2)` is empty for such page?

Comment: Sorry, my error about delete... So your suggestion is only to verify arg(2) and, if it is empty, I can be sure I'm in "view mode"? This means arg(2) always contains the action? Or is there other ways (e.g. specific variables in the page scope) to get it properly?

Comment: I posted a bunch of these rules - hope that helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to check against all paths related to nodes:

Node view:

```
arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) && is_numeric(arg(1)) && !arg(2)
```

Node edit:

```
arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) && arg(2) == 'edit'
```

Node delete:

```
arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) && arg(2) == 'delete'
```

Node add "landing" page from where you choose which content type you want to create:

```
current_path() == 'node/add'
```

Node add page for a specific content type:

```
current_path() == 'node/add/YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE'
```

All node add pages:

```
arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'add' && arg(2)
```